# Change the Console.Foregroundcolor from a string

Tags: c#

I want to output the name of the color in the same color, and the color in question should be taken from user input. I could write something using if statements and naming all the colors, but this wouldn't be elegant enough.

Is there a way to use switch, check for errors in the variable, if the input isn't a color give an error message and otherwise convert the variable to a color and use Console.Foregroundcolor = ConsoleColor.value of the variable?

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name a color");
     string color = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: What about [Console.ForegroundColor Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
        Console.WriteLine("Name a color");
        string color = Console.ReadLine();

        ConsoleColor consoleColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        try
        {
            consoleColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), color, true);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Invalid color
        }

        Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor ;
```

Please note that try catch is used for demonstration only, ideally you should use try parse instead.

Comment: How would it look if I used two cases? One when try fails and one when it works?

Comment: @Patrik: The TryPase returns boolean, so if it is valid color, it will return true and if it is invalid color false will be returned.

Comment: Since it returns a boolean I think this is promising, I could have a switch that in the case it is false it returns an error message and when it is true it uses the string to set the ConsoleColor. But I haven't figured out how to do that yet.

Comment: I ended up writing like this:
     Console.WriteLine("Name a color");
           string color = Console.ReadLine();

           
           try
           {
               Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), color, true);
               
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("That isn't a color");
               Console.ReadLine();
               return;
           }


           Console.WriteLine("You chose " + color);

Comment: @PatrikGustafsson: If you need to use TryParse, just use following - <<        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Name a color");
            string color = Console.ReadLine();

            

            ConsoleColor consoleColor;


            bool isValidColor = Enum.TryParse(color,true, out consoleColor);

            if (isValidColor)
                Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor;

            else //Invalid color
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Color entered !!");
            

            Console.ReadLine();
        }>>

Answer (score 1):

Well [`ForegroundColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses the [`ConsoleColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum so you should be able to use [`Enum.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
ConsoleColor c;
if(Enum.TryParse(color, out c))
    // c is your color you can use
```

Comment: In addition (note to OP); one can use the overload for `ignoreCase`.

Comment: @Silvermind - Thanks, I'll leave that out for some optional research ;)

Comment: Thanks! How would it look if I used case instead?

Comment: @PatrikGustafsson - More or less the same, My link to `Enum.TryParse` has a link to the overload on the left..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

[Console.ForegroundColor Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all known colors

```
KnownColor[] colors = (KnownColor[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
            foreach (KnownColor knowColor in colors)
            {
                Color color = Color.FromKnownColor(knowColor);
                Debug.WriteLine(color.Name);
            }
```

And then use some if inside foreach to check if names match. If so, set new foreground color.